# Display of German Umlautes not displayed correctly in play framework (i18n)

Tags: java, internationalization, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I have the following setting:

**application.conf**

```
application.langs="de"
```

**messages.de**

```
deleteAlbum=Album Löschen
```

And in a template I use:

```
@Messages.get("deleteAlbum")
```

But wenn I view it in the Browser I get:

```
Album L�schen
```

The `messages.de` configuration file has the following encoding:

```
file messages.de 
messages.de: ISO-8859 text
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's a problem with the `Unicode` and `ACSII` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file should be encoded in UTF8. That's at least what was required in Play 1. I assume it's the same with Play 2, although I didn't find anything mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: You are right, I just tested it. Unfortunatelly Idea IDE creates the file automatically as ISO-8859 file, wich is default for java.